# Multiprocessing with gui- cancelling processes

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, multiprocessing, queue

I am working on a gui in python where the purpose is basically to process data in different ways.

I currently have one window for setting up the "runs", and another window for displaying the status of each run (starting, running, finished, error, etc).

I would like to add a feature where the user can *stop* any of the processes from the gui.

I have already worked out how to add a button and associate it with the specific run, but I have not worked out **how to actually stop the process**.
I am using python **multiprocessing** to kick off different tasks because this also allows us to utilize the resources of machine maximally.

```
pool_results = []
pool_results.append(pool.apply_async(func))
```

So far, I have come across **pool.terminate()**, but this simply kills all the child processes.

I've also looked at **multiprocessing.active_children()**, but this gives references to the *workers* created by the pool, not the processes submitted to the pool. The workers are what is associated to a pid etc.

I also found that each "pool result" has an attribute "_job", which is a reference to the order in which processes were added to the pool, but there don't seem to be any functions (hidden or not) that allow me to cancel a job once it is submitted to the pool.

Ideally, I would be able to cancel a process no matter what stage it is in (waiting in queue, being worked on by worker, etc).

Answer (score 1):

When you need advanced functionality, I tend to recommend starting with the `Process` class rather than using pre-built things like `Pool`. It gives you a better understanding of what's going on, and can often be easier (if a bit more verbose) to achieve more advanced behavior. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66019786/3220135) an answer I wrote a little while ago where I implemented my own "Pool" in order to add a bit of extra functionality.

**child processes can die / be terminated in a number of ways:**

- **Ask it nicely :)** If the process is some sort of loop, create some sort of shared value between processes that can signal the child to exit the loop, and shut down.
- If it is [daemonic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon), when the parent process exits it will attempt to call `terminate` on all child processes when it exits.
- You can also call [`terminate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) or [`kill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.kill) the process yourself whenever you want (as long as the process is still running). This will cause the child to be unceremoniously "killed" without any time for things like `atexit` or `try: finally:` things to run. If you do this make sure the child doesn't hold any resources like files or `lock`'s open or have child processes of its own, as these will not be cleaned up properly. see [`signal.signal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) to handle the [`SIGTERM`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIGTERM) signal if you want to attempt any sort of graceful cleanup (you may also want to handle `SIGINT` if you ever use ctrl-c to stop a process from the command line).